# Suppose that $1 ≤ p_1 < p_2 < \infty$. Then each sequence $a_n$ that satisfies $\sum |a_n|^{p_1} < \infty$ also satisfies $\sum |a_n|^{p_2} < \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It might be a subtle problem, but I wonder how to show this convergence statement rigorously.

> Suppose that $1 ≤ p_1 < p_2 < \infty$. Then each sequence $(a_n)$ that satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^{p_1} < \infty$ also satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^{p_2} < \infty$.

I could understand the statement a little bit since if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^{p_1} < \infty$, then the power of this series should be finite. But I fail to formulate my idea.

Any help or any other idea w.r.t the statement would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum |a_n|^{p_1} < \infty$.

Then $\sum_{|a_n|<1} |a_n|^{p_2} \leq \sum_{|a_n|<1} |a_n|^{p_1} < \infty$.

Furthermore, $|a_n|^{p_1} \geq 1$ for at most finite $n$ else $\sum |a_n|^{p_1} = \infty$.

Then $|a_n|^{p_2} \geq 1$ for at most finite $n$.

Hence $\sum_{|a_n|<1} |a_n|^{p_2} < \infty$.

Put these two together to get the result.

Comment: Understood! Many Thanks!

Comment: That is a good proof

Comment: After "Hence" you like to sum over $|a_n|\ge 1$, right? Otherwise the sentence "Put these two together" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Correct that’s the idea